# I've never done a rebus before

Tags: visual, rebus

Each box contains a rebus with a space before the next box, boxes are read left to right top to bottom

[image: The rebus puzzle]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> **A fast brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.** This seems to be a play off the pangram ["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog)

Explanation:

> The lines combine to form the letter *A* = **A**.
> Breakfast - break = **fast**.
> Brow + own = **brown**.
> F + ox = **fox**.
> J + hump + S = **jumps**.
> "Getting over it" - (getting + *It*) = **over**.
> **A**.
> Lays + Y = **lazy**.
> **Dog**.

Comment: This was a bit too easy

Comment: @pfg At least it was fun :)

Comment: Lays + Y was easy, but it is a very fun rebus.